# Adding text at a specific place in an HTML file using Python File IO

Tags: python, html, file-io, beautifulsoup

I currently have an HTML file with words that run a script on click. What I want to do on click is insert some text in line. Below is an example of what I want to have have happen.

I want to go from this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>
A whole bunch of words yada yada yada
<a href="#" onclick="pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>
more words yada yada yada
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To this...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>
    <p>
    A whole bunch of words yada yada yada
    <a href="#" onclick="pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)" title="Mercury poisoning">
     mercury poisoning
    </a>
    </p>
    <p> Text that comes from pythonScript
    </p>
    <p>
    more words yada yada yada
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note that the text coming from the python script is already in html format. How would I do this using Python File IO? If it is easier to do with another tool, what is the simplest tool to use for this problem?

I tried to use the write function but that overwrote the entire file. Then I tried writing in append mode but that still did not place the text where I wanted it. My third idea was to open the file in r+ mode and read until the word I clicked but I do not know how to ensure that the program will come to the correct string as opposed to the first instance of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do this with just the Python standard library, the following code snippet should work.

```
initial_code = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>
A whole bunch of words yada yada yada
<a href="#" onclick="pythonScript(/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)" title="Mercury poisoning">
 mercury poisoning
</a>
more words yada yada yada
</p>
</body>
</html>
'''

additional_code = '''
    <p> Text that comes from pythonScript
    </p>
'''

elements = initial_code.split("more words yada yada yada")

new_file = elements[0] + additional_code + elements [1]
```

However, this is not a great general-purpose solution.  Depending on what you would like your script to do, it might be a better fit to use a templating library like [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) to build your HTML page.  Miguel Grinberg has a [great tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates) on using Jinja2 in a Flask app, and introduces the concept of templates.